# Problem with permutations

Tags: core-language, permutation

For a given binary array like `{0, 1, 1, 0,..}`, I need to find *the shortest* permutation, sorting it in standard order `{0,0,...,1,1,..}`.
There is a warning in documentations for `FindPermutation`:

> For expressions containing repeated parts, the permutation is not
> uniquely defined

And it's easily to find the next example:

```
  data = {1, 1, 0};
  FindPermutation[data, Sort@data]
  (*Don't confuse it with FindPermutation@data,
  it's not the same!*)
 Output: Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}]
(*Also:*)
PermutationCycles@Ordering@data
Output: Cycles[{{1, 3, 2}}]
```

But:

```
 Permute[data, Cycles[{{1, 3}}]]
    Output: {0, 1, 1}
```

So `FindPermutation` produces not shortest result. And how to find shortest not manually?
Is it possible to find *all* that produce the same result?

Comment: @bmf  Edit post, I mean warnings in the docs

Comment: Maybe Ordering will help?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, yes I tried `PermutationCycles@Ordering@arr`, but does this guarantee shortest result?

Comment: Please keep it civil, people. We're all friends here and it happens that someone misinterprets the meaning.

Comment: I believe `Ordering` is "stable" in the sense that equal elements won't get swapped. So it should give a minimal permutation (he said).

Answer (score 1):

The only direct method that I've found is (without useless `FindPermutation`) :

```
data = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0};
perms = Permutations@Range@Length@data;
res = MinimalBy[Select[perms, data[[#]] == Sort@data &], 
  PermutationOrder]

Output: {{1, 5, 6, 4, 2, 3}, {1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2}}
```

This code guarantees shortest length of permutations that produce sorted `data`.
Shorter and smarter result is very welcome!